# AngularJS - Creating and retrieving dynamically created forms

Tags: forms, angularjs, dynamic

I have a form that has an 'Attributes' section. The user can add as many Attributes as he/she wants:

HTML:

```
<h4>
   Attributes:
   <input type="button" value="+" id="new_obj_att_add" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
</h4>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attribute in attributes">
    <input type="text" ng-model="att_name" placeholder="Attribute Name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="att_value" placeholder="Attribute Value">
    <hr>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.attributes = [{id: 1}];
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.attributes.length+1;
    $scope.attributes.push({'id': newItemNo});
};
```

Now, that code works wonderfully for dynamically growing the form. However, I need to pass the form data back into my controller. As you can see, every attribute is going to have the same ng-model, so I can't get it from there.

1) Is there a way to dynamically assign the ng-model name using the ID of each attribute (ie. attr_name_1, attr_name_2), then loop through those elements within my AngularJS formula and gather the values that way?

2) Am I just not creating these elements the right way if I'm going to reference them again in AngularJS?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to assign it to the model in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attribute in attributes">
    <input type="text" ng-model="attribute.att_name" placeholder="Attribute Name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="attribute.att_value" placeholder="Attribute Value">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Then the values are automatically assigned to the right model in the `attributes` collection.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I reference that back in my JS? Say I call a function from HTML of printAttributes(attributes), I'm not sure how to iterate through that list of attributes and get the name/value.

Comment: The attributes are in `$scope.attributes` you can access them the exact same way you did it for adding a new attribute. For the loop you can use `angular.forEach`.